# Ember run later in coffeescript not working correctly

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript

I am pretty new to Ember so I am totally stumped by this. The run later appears to work however it seems to ignore the fact that it is supposed to only run once every 5 seconds to update the status, it actually seems to just continually and immediately keep calling the getServers method and then immediately call itself (startWatchingStatus) again. Because of this code the page never actually gets rendered. I must be doing something wrong in this code:

```
App.ServersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(

    startWatchingStatus: () ->
        controller = @
        controller.getServers()
        Ember.run.later(controller, () ->
        controller.startWatchingStatus()
        , 5000)

    getServers: () ->
        App.ServerObject.getServers().done((data) ->
            controller.set('content', data)
            )

    init: () ->
        @_super()
        controller = @
        controller.startWatchingStatus()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the usage of [`Ember.run.later`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html#method_later), it will wait 5000ms and then execute your method, it won't keep repeating it for you. For that you could either chain the calls to `Ember.run.later` like this (sorry, don't know coffescript but you'll get the idea):

```
var callback = () => {
  this.getServers();
  Ember.run.later(this, callback, 5000);
};

Ember.run.later(controller, callback, 5000);
```

Or you could go with a simple `window.setInterval` and wrap it within a runloop inside.

```
window.setInterval(()  => {
  Ember.run(() => {
    controller.getServers();
  });
}, 5000);
```

The second one might be easier if you need to be cancel the interval later on but it's up to you which one you prefer.

Comment: I will give your suggestions a try, but the way my code should keep repeating the method because it should be running getServers() then waiting 5 seconds and then calling itself (startWatchingStatus) again.

Comment: Oh right, misread that part. My code should be put in `startWatchingStatus` and then call `getServers` each time. I'll update the samples.

Comment: With the changes your first option is the same as what I already have apart from mine being written in coffeescript. I am starting to think it is the coffee script that is causing me issues specifically with the function that I am passing in.

Comment: I just ran your code through the coffescript compiler at http://coffeescript.org and as far as I can see it seems to be sensitive to indentation. Since `controller.startWatchingStatus()` is on the same indentation level as your `Ember.run.later` it won't be used as the body of your callback. Adding two spaces in front of it seems to do the trick.

Comment: that was my issue, thanks you so much. All those hours over two spaces. tried it with 4, tried it with 0, didn't try it with 2. That online compiler is bound to come in handy too.